# Add customized buttons to the existing MessageBox

Tags: wpf, messagebox

How can I add custom buttons to the existing `MessageBox` in WPF? Apart from the usual Ok and Cancel buttons, I need to add 3 more buttons and also handle their events.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: No it is not possible, you need to write a new window.

Long answer: the MessageBox class uses the Win32 MessageBox (or maybe MessageBoxEx) function, this function does not support extending the message box.

It is possible to modify the message box after it is opened, but:

1. It is a lot of work
2. It isn't supported
3. you have to do it using Win32 directly, the message box window is not WPF or even WinForms.

All in all, it's less work to write a window with one TextBlock, one Image and 5 buttons than to mess around with internal implementation details of the MessageBox code.