# message box with button "Yes to All" and "No to All"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, messagebox

Is this possible? The [MessageBox.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx) methods apparently force me to use one of the [MessageBoxButton enums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons.aspx), and none of them has the Yes to all and no to all option. Is it possible to display a message box dialog having Yes To All and No to All?

Comment: You'll need to write your own custom message box. There are questions about this already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add customized buttons to the existing Messagebox in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063005/how-to-add-customized-buttons-to-the-existing-messagebox-in-wpf)

Comment: the links obviously point to WinForm classes …

Answer (score 4):

You can always create your own dialog that looks like a MessageBox and has the buttons you need. I don't think you can override MessageBox's look.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which technology you are actually using (both WinForms and WPF are tagged) these articles should give you a good place to start.

WPF Common TaskDialog for Vista and XP:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFTaskDialogVistaAndXP.aspx

Customizable WPF Messagebox:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/05/26/a-customizable-wpf-messagebox.aspx

WinForms - Disecting the Messagebox:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/MessageBoxEx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

MessageBox is Windows Forms component. It would be not best idea to use it in WPF applications. But If you want to try, you could find something useful [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/messagebox-in-wpf/)